# Ideals of Banach algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ideals

Is there any characterization of ideals space or maximal ideals space of following Banach algebras?

1)$C^1{([0,1])}$

2) disc algebra

3)$A(SO(3))$

Comment: Classifying all the ideals is hard. Classifying all the maximal ideals is the same as finding the character space and this should be something one can work out from one's own knowledge or from books such as Rickart, Bonsall and Duncan, Dales, Kaniuth...

Comment: BTW, I feel like I recognize these three particular examples from suggestions and comments I made in some previous answer or comment to some other question...

Comment: Yes. I want to see ideals structure of non amenable semisimple Banach algebras and I use your previous good answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to answer the easy part of the question quickly

1) [0,1]

2) the closed unit disc

3) SO(3)